# How to refresh a button icon, indicating that it's working before a heavy a job starts

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

```
def generate_thumb(self):
        # -- clear preview image
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.nwidth, self.nheight)
        pixmap.fill( QColor('#C0C0C0'))
        ico = QIcon(pixmap)
        self.btn3.setIcon(ico)      
        self.btn3.show()    # still not showing 
        self.generate_thumbnail()
```

I want btn3 filled with a grey background visible to the user - and then to start the thumbnail generation (takes 5-10 seconds then the btn3 icon is filled again with the generated thumbnail). When I run the code I don't see the grey background at all, only the new rendered image after the generation is done.

How can I force the gui to refresh or show the grey btn3 icon and then start to generate the the new image?

Answer (score 1):

I just finally found the answer myself.

calling `QtGui.qApp.processEvents()` worked for me

```
def generate_thumb(self):
        # -- clear preview image
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.nwidth, self.nheight)
        pixmap.fill( QColor('#C0C0C0'))
        ico = QIcon(pixmap)
        self.btn3.setIcon(ico)      

        #  show it now!
        QtGui.qApp.processEvents()       

        self.generate_thumbnail()
```